# Implementing angular-calendar in Angular 4 CLI project

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar

New to Angular - Having trouble getting this angular-calendar component found here https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar implemented into my project.

I'm setting up a basic project using the Angular CLI. Following the Getting Started guide, I don't know how or where to include the .css file. I've tried a few spots.

After I couldn't figure that out, I went to the build-tools/angular-CLI page of the repo and cloned it. I'm assuming this is a basic project created using the Angular CLI?

When I ng serve -o this project, it's just a calendar. Missing a lot of the features that I want, found here -

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

It looks like this [image]

Can someone help me implement a calendar into a project that was just created using the Angular CLI? Very similar to how it looks here -

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `just a calendar`?

Comment: Added a screenshot. For example, month is not displayed, can't change month etc. Sorry it's very hard to see.

Comment: do i understand correctly that you cloned this project:  https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink and then you run `ng serve` in it, but it's calendar is not the way it's in site?

Comment: I've cloned that projected located here https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/tree/master/build-tool-examples/angular-cli

Comment: That's the only thing that made sense to me.

Comment: You did wrong, i'll post answer now

Comment: Thank you! I'm now trying just doing the repo found on the main page to see what that does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an npm package, so first you should create angular project, you can do it easily via Angular CLI `ng new`. Then you should open terminal/bash in project directory and do `npm i`, then `npm i --save angular-calendar`.

Go to AppModule.ts and add calendar module, your code in appModule should be sth like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-
browser/animations';
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Then go to file `.angular-cli.json` it is in your project root. Find section `styles` and add `node_modules/angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css` there.

it should be sth like this:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
        "../node_modules/angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css",
        "scss/style.scss"
      ],
```

Then go back to project root and for example generate a component `ng g component calendComp` and use the calendar over there as it's described in it's documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I've generated the component but don't know how to use the calendar. I've tried including the <app-calend-comp> tag in my main app component but all that points to is calend-comp.component.html which just prints  calend-comp works!.

Comment: Now you can use calendar as shown in https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink see component.ts and template.html

Comment: How did you try to include `<app-calend-comp>` in your main app component?

Comment: Please if the answer i have given is correct then accept it

Comment: Do I need to generate a component called "DemoComponent" since that's what's used in the example. Also in the calend-comp.component.ts file import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; is missing?

Comment: I tried to add <app-calend-comp> as a tag in my app.component.html file.

Comment: You can use your calend-comp instead of demoComponent, main thing is that your calend-comp should be similar to demoComponent in usage of calendar directives. You can add boostrap if you are going to use it. You can google `how to install ng-boostrap angular 2 npm` , it should be sth like `npm i --save ng-boostrap`